# How to get the sum with NVL in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

Please help, i don't know how to get the sum of two data with NVL function and display it as two result only

Desired output:

```
 Data, date, total no. of g column, total no. of u column
```

Here's some query:

```
 SELECT 'Data'
 ||','||To_char(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

--I want to get the sum of this portion

```
 ||','||NVL(g.POS, 0)
 ||','||NVL(g.Office, 0)
```

--I want to get the sum of this portion

```
 ||','||NVL(u.POS, 0)
 ||','||NVL(u.Office, 0)
 FROM owner_dwh.dc_date d
```

Comment: Please show your tables. Is it three different tables d, g and u? How are they related?

Answer (score 1):

In order to have sums, you want to use the `sum` aggregate function and `group by` the remaining selected columns:

```
SELECT 
  'Data'
  ||','||To_char(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
  ||','||SUM(NVL(g.POS, 0))
  ||','||SUM(NVL(g.Office, 0))
  ||','||SUM(NVL(u.POS, 0))
  ||','||SUM(NVL(u.Office, 0))
 FROM 
   owner_dwh.dc_date d 
 GROUP BY
   To_char(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy'),
   NVL(u.POS, 0),
   NVL(u.Office, 0)
```

I suspect that there is more to your question, but without further information, this is how far we can help.

Also, it should be noted that `sum()` doesn't require `nvl()` if `null` is to be replaced by `0`. `sum` does this automatically. I have left the `nvl()` in my answer .

**Maybe**, after re-reading your question, what you want is this;

```
SELECT 
  'Data'
  ||','||To_char(d.dtime_day, 'MM/dd/yyyy')
  ||','||NVL(g.POS, 0))
  ||','||NVL(g.Office, 0))
  ||','|| (NVL(g.POS, 0) + NVL (g.Office, 0))
  ||','||NVL(u.POS, 0)
  ||','||NVL(u.Office, 0)
  ||','|| (NVL(u.POS, 0) + NVL (u.Office, 0))
 FROM owner_dwh.dc_date d
```

Comment: but i get an a error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"